# Error when using nextInt in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a program for my classes lab and I seem to be using nextInt wrong and I was wondering if someone could help. I couldn't find a post that had an answer. The program is designed to experiment with loops in a rolling dice simulation. It it supposed to roll two dice, determine the result, and then make a tally if it's snake eyes or doubles or whatever it may be.

So I get the following error:

```
DiceSimulation.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
     die1Value = nextInt();
                 ^
symbol:   method nextInt()
location: class DiceSimulation

DiceSimulation.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
     die2Value = nextInt();
                 ^
symbol:   method nextInt()
location: class DiceSimulation
2 errors
```

This is the code I have, I'm not entirely sure how I've used nextInt wrong.

```
   while (count < NUMBER)
   {
     die1Value = nextInt();
     die2Value = nextInt();
     if (die1Value == die2Value)
     {
        if (die1Value == 1)
        {   
           snakeEyes += 1;
        }
        else if (die1Value == 2)
        {   
           twos += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 3)
        {   
           threes += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 4)
        {   
           fours += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 5)
        {   
           fives += 1;
        }   
        else if (die1Value == 6)
        {   
           sixes += 1;   
        }
      }
      count += 1;
   }
```

Comment: Is it `nextInt()` from `Scanner` class?

Comment: you don't have a method `nextInt()` in your code, that's what the error is telling you

Comment: [`random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) - you need to specify the appropriate [Random] object instance ..

Answer (score 4):

[`Random#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) is neither a static method, nor built-in - you have to have an instance of the `Random` class to use it.

Here's an example:

```
Random dice = new Random();
int die1Value = dice.nextInt(6) + 1;
int die2Value = dice.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

The addition of 1 there is to offset the fact that a random value with a range bound generates values between [0, n).

Comment: Asker wants to roll two dice, not ask for input.

Comment: So it's *not* a `Scanner`, but a `Random`.  Two seconds.

Comment: Still doesn't work; you have to specify the range of the int to return.

Comment: Indeed, `nextInt()` is quite ambiguous on its own. I made the same mistake reading the OP's question

Comment: @Saposhiente:  As far as it "working", the signature is correct.  As far as it working within the bounds of the program, perhaps you have a point - using `nextInt(n)` would be correct.